# Is there a web service for converting HTML to PDF?

Tags: html, web-services, pdf

Is there a web service for converting HTML to PDF?

Currently we are doing this ourselves, but we would like to take this load off our servers.

Comment: htm2pdf.co.uk is another one that seems to be missing from the below answers

Comment: You could also try GrabzIt's HTML to PDF API: http://grabz.it/html-to-pdf-image-api.aspx

Comment: SelectPdf HTML to PDF REST API can be used for this: https://selectpdf.com/html-to-pdf-api/

Comment: Another reliable REST API solution https://products.aspose.cloud/pdf is missing from the options list.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For third party solutions there are lots of options. Just to name a few...

- https://cloudlayer.io
- https://www.api2pdf.com
- https://www.printfriendly.com
- https://pdfshift.io
- http://pdfmyurl.com/html-to-pdf-api
- https://www.html2pdfrocket.com/
- https://pdflayer.com/
- http://pdfcrowd.com/
- http://www.pdfonline.com/convert-pdf/
- http://docraptor.com
- https://restpack.io/html2pdf
- https://products.aspose.cloud/pdf
- https://pdfmage.org/

Comment: I have tested a number of these and have found http://pdfcrowd.com to be the most reliable (on their forums they claim it uses Chrome/WebKit as the engine to render the PDF.  I believe it based on the reliable output I've seen, even when pages modify the DOM and draw with JavaScript).  The other good one seems to be http://web2pdfconvert.com

Comment: some of these are based on old technology, like pdfcrowd, which seems to be based on QT4.7 and is no longer under development. htm2pdf seems to working with the latest version of webkit and is the only one I found keeps an active development record

Comment: I tested all your links... the best for me is pdfcrowd. Thanks @jpeskin for the suggestion.

Comment: Note, all of these except DocRaptor are using open-source PDF converters like wkhtmltopdf. DocRaptor uses the Prince commercial library, which typically makes higher quality and smaller PDFs and provides more formatting options.

Comment: https://www.html2pdfwebservice.com is another one.

Answer (score 17):

[DocRaptor](http://docraptor.com/) should do the trick. It's a web service, so you'll be able to give your server a break.

Comment: I prefer DocRaptor to others because Heroku now has this service as Add-On.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the Python ReportLab library from Google's AppEngine, or if you are happy to use a 3rd-party service, [PDFCrowd](http://pdfcrowd.com/) will do this for you.

Comment: Hi, this python library is working for me, but for some cases the converted pdf doesn't  have text format. It shows it as an image. What I am telling is I can't search for words using Ctrl + F. Any guesses??

Answer (score 0):

I use this one http://htmlpdf.com/ and this one I've just discovered http://pdf-ace.com/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18079519)

Comment: @DonBoitnott OK, so does this mean I should delete the answer? Let me know please.

Comment: As this is:  1) quite old;  2) closed as off-topic;  3) exactly like the accepted answer...  Just leave it.  The comment was auto-generated by the review queue, btw.

Comment: Okay, thanks for letting me know.