# How to export a auto generated HTML to PDF

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf

I have the following code which is partially what my HTML page does.

```
<script>
function close() {
    MainJavaScript();
}
function MainJavaScript()
{
    //var strEntity = " ";
    var strEntity = document.getElementById('Entity').value;
    //Images setup by Entity
    if (strEntity == "MGP") 
    {
        document.getElementById('displayPic').src="http://mgp75.png";
    }
    else if (strEntity == "MPP")
    {
        document.getElementById('displayPic').src="http://mpp75.png";
    }
    else if (strEntity == "RSC")
    {
        document.getElementById('displayPic').src="http://rsc75.png";
    }
    else if (strEntity == "MSN")
    {
        document.getElementById('displayPic').src="http://msn75.png";
    }

    var strFirstName = "John";
    var strLastName = "Doe";
    var strSuffix = " ";
    var strTitle = "DDS";
    var strSecondaryTitle = " ";
    var strDisplayName = strFirstName + " " + strLastName;
    if (strTitle.trim() != '')
        strDisplayName += ", " + strTitle;
    if (strSuffix.trim() != '')
        strDisplayName += ", " + strSuffix;
    if (strSecondaryTitle.trim() !='')
        strDisplayName += ", " + strSecondaryTitle;


    document.getElementById('FullName').innerHTML = strDisplayName;
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:close()">Submit</a>


<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="55%">

            <div class="first">
                <div class="contact-info">
                    <h3><img id="displayPic" src="" alt=""></h3>
                </div><!--// .contact-info -->
            </div>
        </td>
        <td width="40%">
            <div>
                <h1><font color="#003893" face="Georgia">Cu Vi</font></h1>
                <h2><span id="FullName"></span></h2>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I click the `Submit` button the `displayPic` and the `FullName` is replaced by the respective values using `MainJavascript` function. What I am looking to do is create a PDF from the output but unfortunately all the DLLs and method I found requires me to output a HTML file and then convert to a PDF but because it is using JavaScript, the source is always blank but the display is changed once the button is clicked.

How can I achieve what I am looking to do, is convert the output into a PDF?

Answer (score 2):

You should look at Xep CloudFormatter.  This library, jquery plugin, prints any html page.  So, given your example, if I were to start with an HTML template like you have, and then with javascript/jquery I populate the html and then call xepOnline.Formatter.Format to render it, you will get back a beautiful PDF.

I simplified your code a bit, but here is a fiddle for you to explore:

http://jsfiddle.net/kstubs/56x6W/

```
function printMe() {
  tryAtMain();
  var imgLoad = imagesLoaded($('#displayPic')[0]);
  imgLoad.on( 'always', function() {
      xepOnline.Formatter.Format('print_me', {
          pageMargin: ".25in"
      });
  });
}

function tryAtMain() {
// some pic
$('#displayPic').attr('src','http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-370-222-1.jpg');
$('#FullName').html('Johnny Carson');
}
```

Comment: Note:  the jsFiddle solution needs a "wait for image to load" before formatting begins.  Incidentally, the 2nd time you hit "print me" the image appears (its cached).  I'll work on that wait..

Comment: Nice use of imagesLoaded. That seems to work everytime!

Comment: Thank you. Can I avoid JQuery all together? I can only use JS.

Comment: Does it have to be the latest JQuery library? Because I am getting a `Line: 155 \n Error: 'length' is null or not an object`

Comment: We have committed several new features (including support for embedding YouTube videos) and bug fixes in the last couple of hours.  Would you mind testing again?  We haven't yet done a full analysis of which versions of jQuery the library supports.  We are developing with jQuery v1.11.1 -- Firefox, Safari, and Chrome browser support is excellent, however IE min version right now is 10.  Don't forget to visit this page frequently as each time we develop something new we showcase it here:  http://xep.cloudformatter.com/doc/

Comment: @kstubs I tried to print out as PDF, but the look and feel changes when the PDF is generated from what the HTML looks like. :/

Comment: Here is my http://jsfiddle.net/56x6W/12/ as you can see the PDF is not formatted as it is seen in the HTML. How can I fix it?

Comment: First of all @SearchForKnowledge we appreciate your sample very much!  We solved and improved our libraries considerably since your sample was given.  You'll find that this this fiddle is very close to your original HTML.  We did have to change your td width property to a style property like:  <td style="width:55%">  Other than this, everything is what you originally proposed.  There is one other style issue that we are working on, and that seems to be the margin on the container that floats left, it is off.  Here's that fiddle:  http://fiddle.jshell.net/kstubs/56x6W/

Comment: @kstubs Thank you very much for the response. I just tested it but inside the PERSONAL DATA the bold text doesn't appear in the PDF :/

Comment: Hi @SearchForKnowledge we have done extensive testing with floats.  We did find a couple of issues that we have now solved but it doesn't solve your's quite yet.  However, what is the source of your HTML document?  The markup and use of floats and the bloated CSS seems all well too much, too complicated.  Are you producing this markup or is some software/product producing it?  I could redesign this page in probably 30 min with 10% of the code used.

Comment: @kstubs I have to say you are DEDICATED!!! Thank you. It is being produced by another software unfortunately... I am sure we can do it another way but I didn't want to spend too much time on it :/