# Add non chart content in highchart pdf

Tags: highcharts, css-to-pdf

Can we add non-svg chart related content in the PDF we create using highcharts?

I used this example for [creating PDF of multiple highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40485710/highchart-download-multiple-graph-on-individual-page).

I want to add custom logo and some title at the top of the graph PDF. For example logo of website with title "Graph for life cycle"

Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: What in this example is not what you wish ... http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.SVGCharts.HighCharts. The menus at the top format multiple highchart charts and also content.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the image and text to appear in the PDF, but not on the screen.  To achieve that, just add a class to the elements that is limited to a print media query.

```
@media print {
  .noScreen {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen {
  .noScreen {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=MyLogo' class='noScreen'>
  <h1 class='noScreen'>Graph for life cycle</h1>
```

I've modified the sample fiddle from that answer to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/zvx6eb7e/646/