# how to convert total html page to pdf using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I  tried to convert a html page with dynamic values in it's totality to pdf but i can't. I saw some api  like **jspdf** but that doesn't suit my needs. Can anybody recommend a Javascript or jQuery library that fits this purpose?

Comment: This was a bad close. Wonder why good questions like these are closed just like this :/

Comment: Why is this closed? :|

Comment: Please take off this close, its for no reason

Comment: You could try GrabzIt's JavaScript library: https://grabz.it/api/javascript/ you can do something along the lines of: 

    GrabzIt("Application Key").ConvertURL("http://www.google.com").Create();

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a little snippet which works locally - you can change to suitable your host set up:

```
URL url = new File("test.html").toURI().toURL();
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(); 
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);

OutputStream os = null;
try{
   os = new FileOutputStream("test.pdf");

   ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
   renderer.setDocument(page,url.toString());
   renderer.layout();
   renderer.createPDF(os);
} finally{
   if(os != null) os.close();
}
```

Alternatively, here's the link to jsPDF: http://code.google.com/p/jspdf

Here's a useful example using jsPDF:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
doc.text(20, 30, 'This is client-side Javascript, pumping out a PDF.');
doc.addPage();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Do you like that?');

// Output as Data URI
doc.output('datauri');
```

More information can be found here: http://snapshotmedia.co.uk/blog/jspdf

Comment: May i have the code snippet for the above Webclient in C#. Really not understanding how this stuff works.. :P

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to convert each page of pdf to html file?

Comment: Billy, your comment goes off a little off topic. Perhaps open a new question for this or try some available solutions (search in Google) and open a question with anything you get stuck on.

Comment: George Stocker - I'm not sure why you've close this question. This chap had a genuine question and people seem to find the answer useful. Can I suggest you reopen it please? Would be helpful to the community.

Comment: What's the problem with this question? I also need answer to this. It is totally constructive.