# How to export a html page to pdf in client side using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

And if it is not possible then what are the other alternatives?

I tried to convert a complete html page to pdf with dynamic values but I can't .

But I saw some API like *jspdf* but it is not useful for me.

Is it possible to save a HTML page as PDF file using JavaScript or jQuery?

In Detail:

I generated one HTML Page which contains a list grid which populated all the available reports dynamically. It has one button 'save as PDF'. If the user clicks this button then the HTML page will be converted to a PDF file.

Is it possible using JavaScript or jquery?

Comment: you can not do this on the clientside, you need at least one php file which generates a pdf file for you if you want to covert a complete html page to pdf   also possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896592 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742271 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975694

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to save HTML page as PDF using JavaScript or jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896592/is-it-possible-to-save-html-page-as-pdf-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: also you can use the print function in browsers but it makes more sense and always works to use AJAX + a PHP based converter like TCPDF

Answer (score 10):

jsPDF has a HTML renderer but it is in the early stages:

https://github.com/mrrio/jsPDF

http://parall.ax/products/jspdf

Another solution might be https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js

But the best solution is the one from mujaffars. User AJAX and a stable PDF library written in PHP like FPDF, PDFLib, TCPDF and others.

Comment: They still say the html-renderer is experimental, 5 years later.

Comment: They don't support CSS, so only useable for really basic PDFs.

Comment: @JDK92 the answer is almost 9 years old. There might be better solutions now. Do you know any good solutions, that would work?

Comment: @DanielRuf that's right, but unfortunately not much has changed. I couldn't find a reliable solution and for me the best way was to use the "Print -> Save to PDF" function in the browser as it seems to interpret the CSS fairly well.

Comment: @JDK92 I agree. Unfortunately there is no way (due to security reasons) to enforce "pdf" as printer and trigger the final "print" button. In our projects we implement a "window.print()" call or have some rather big solutions on the backend side like wkhtmltopdf and similar.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if I have got your question properly then u need to `Export a Table Data as PDF`?

If Yes, then please see [datatables.js](http://www.datatables.net/) with simple example [here](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/).

Also, look into [use BytescoutPDF.js (Bytescout PDF Generator for JavaScript) to draw PDF invoice](http://bytescout.com/products/developer/pdfgeneratorsdkjs/create_pdf_invoice_javascript.html)  and [JSPDF](http://parall.ax/products/jspdf#) you can get the details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742271/generating-pdf-files-with-javascript).

Comment: But this is not meant to convert a complete HTML page But this is not meant to convert a complete HTML page to PDF directly to PDF

Answer (score -2):

You need to use any pdf generating library. You have not specified in which technology you are working (Php, .net or anything else)

In PHP you can use tcpdf library, Where you can pass html to generate pdf

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->writeHTML($pdfHtml, true, false, true, false, '');
```

Where $pdfHtml will be your page html

In your case when clicking on 'save as pdf' button you can get html by using html() method of jquery

eg.

```
var pageHtml = $('html').html();
```

by passing pageHtml to ajax page, You can create pdf in ajax page

Comment: The title clearly states `in client side`, php, .net and other server-side technologies are out of the question.

Answer (score -6):

It is possible indeed with **`pdf.js`** plugin
**`pdf.js`** is an HTML5 experiment that explores building a faithful and efficient PDF renderer without native code assistance.

**[Online Demo](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html)**

**[Github Link](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js)**

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/RjqUf/20/)**

Comment: pdf.js just reads PDF files and generates HTML data from it, so mthis is the wrong direction