# Converting HTML page to pdf with more than 5 pages

Tags: c#, html, .net, pdf

I'm trying to add a feature to my webapp to store a HTML page as a pdf. The thing is, my app generates HTML reports which are normally longer than 5 pages( can go upto 15), I found this library online "Select.PDF" which efficiently works with a limitation of 5 pages. Can somebody help or advise me for handing a situation with more than 5 pages.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to save HTML page as PDF using JavaScript or jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896592/is-it-possible-to-save-html-page-as-pdf-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

In their website they have clearly mention the Html to Pdf Converter Community Edition Features.  It would allow you to Generate pdf documents up to 5 pages 
[click here for more details](http://selectpdf.com/community-edition/)

Answer (score 0):

I donot know why you are using this , as there is default functionality available in google chrome browser just press ctrl+P and look into left pane there is an option to SAVE as XPS or PDF just select PDF and your whole html page regardless of page no.s will be saved as PDF

Still if you want to do it via code just use itextsharp dll its 3rd party dll can convert content into pdf via C#.

Comment: I want provide an option "Save as pdf" in my webapp, that's the reason I was looking for some dll.. Thanks for the suggestion