# Make a PDF from a HTML page in landscape format

Tags: javascript, php, html, jspdf

I need to make a PDF in landscape format.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        var specialElementHandlers = {
            '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
                return true;
            }
        };
        $('#cmd').click(function () {
            doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
                'width': 170,
                'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
            });
            doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to save HTML page as PDF using JavaScript or jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896592/is-it-possible-to-save-html-page-as-pdf-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: I don't understand how this can slove my Problem? There is nothing about the landscape format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found it out. It is so simple :)  The first Param is for landscape in `jsPDF()` which is `l` for landscape.

`var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', [297, 210]); //The first Param is for landscape or portrait`

Answer (score 1):

**app.component.ts**

```
@ViewChild('pdfContent') pdfContent: ElementRef;

 async capture() {

// var doc = new jspdf("p", "pt", "a4");  // For Portrait

var doc = new jspdf('l', 'pt', "a4");  // For landscape
//code


})
```

**app.component.html**

```
 <div class="col-md-12" class="tablejoin" #pdfContent id = 
 "entireTable" >
<table> .. </table>
</div>
```

Comment: When answering questions on Stack Overflow, it's important to explain the answer so that people can learn from it.  It's also important to answer directly.  Your answer here adds a lot of unnecessary code which can be confusing, preventing people from learning from you.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the suggestion. I shall correct it.

Answer (score 1):

use the below code for portrait mode.

```
    var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', 'a4'); // optional parameters
    doc.addImage(img/imgdata, 'PNG', 10, 10, 280, 180);
    doc.save("new.pdf");
```

Configure dimension while adding the image or data for pdf.

Comment: What is jsPDF here? Can you describe it in detail?