# How to convert HTML page to PDF then download it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, pdf-generation

This is my web page designed with HTML and CSS:

[image]

How can I download the same web page as PDF? I was trying many solutions but I am getting only content on PDF file but not with CSS style.

Any solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to save HTML page as PDF using JavaScript or jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896592/is-it-possible-to-save-html-page-as-pdf-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 24):

As explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32625547/6331369) you can use the [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) library to do that.

Make sure to include both [`jQuery`](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js) and [`jsPDF`](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js) in your file.

Also get [html2canvasJS](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to convert the document elements to canvas in order to fix the CSS.

**JS:**

```
let doc = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');

doc.addHTML(document.body,function() {
    doc.save('html.pdf');
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

<div id="content">
  <h1 style="color:red">Hello World</h1>
  <p>this is a PDF</p>
</div>
```

**Demo:** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1vwnpxsg/2/)

You can also trigger the download with a button ([see initial post for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32625547/6331369))

Comment: I've tried that but it wont display as per the given style(css)

Comment: @YashParekh If you find this answer helpful don't forget to up vote / accept for future users

Comment: html2canvas don't work properly for pages with map on it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the latest version of [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF).
2. Include the following Scripts in your project:

   - jspdf.js
   - jspdf.plugin.from_html.js
   - jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js
   - jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js