# How to turn an html/css form into a pdf without changing its css layout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

I have a form which contains certain fields . So , What I want is, when the user enters those certain fields and submits the form , it should generate a PDF out of it. Can anyone help me out it ?

What I have done is , I have redirected the form to a new HTML page, got all the data which has to be processed to new page. And then I am stuck as to how to proceed . I am using the naive method of saving the generated HTML and then converting that generated HTML to PDF from command line .

Is there a better method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to get a pdf from your html

1. `window.print();` in JS
2. already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896592/is-it-possible-to-save-html-page-as-pdf-using-javascript-or-jquery) using jquery, but only to a certain degree, it doesn't support colors or images or other things
3. lastly I recommend [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) which was another answer to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896592/is-it-possible-to-save-html-page-as-pdf-using-javascript-or-jquery) somewhat like yours

Comment: jsPDF with HTML2Canvas is what i used in the past