# Export html table to PDF and preserve the tables look

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, html-table

I have the following table:

```js
var currencySymbol = '£'
var total = 0.0;
$('table tbody tr:gt(0) td:nth-child(4)').each(function() {
  total += parseFloat($(this).html().replace(currencySymbol, ''));
});

total += currencySymbol;

var $newTR = $("<tr><td colSpan='3'></td><td>"+total+"</td><td></td></tr>");
$('table tbody').append($newTR);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-bordered">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Timestamp</td>
         <td>Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Shop Name</td>
         <td>Amount</td>
         <td>Comments</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>10/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>J's Pizza Stop </td>
         <td>72.75£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-11 16:53 Full Amount: 75 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 2.25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>13/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Mexican House</td>
         <td>93.42£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-18 10:08 Full Amount: 96.31 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 2.8893</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>14/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Mexican House</td>
         <td>67.08£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-18 10:05 Full Amount: 69.15 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 2.0745</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>18/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Mexican House</td>
         <td>94.00£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-25 10:34 Full Amount: 96.91 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 2.9073</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>19/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Mexican House</td>
         <td>48.50£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-25 10:34 Full Amount: 50 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 1.5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>20/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Mexican House</td>
         <td>34.85£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-25 10:33 Full Amount: 35.93 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 1.0779</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>25/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Eastham Express</td>
         <td>212.97£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-02-01 10:51 Full Amount: 219.56 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 6.5868</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>03/02/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>J's Pizza Stop </td>
         <td>14.55£</td>
         <td>Full Amount: 15 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 0.45</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there a plugin that I can use to export the table to a PDF and preserve its structure and look the way it looks in the example above? So far I've tried using `jspdf`but didn't manage to preserve the table structure and the examples I've seen on `stackoverflow` haven't manage to do that as well. Can someone point me to a working example of how to export the table to a PDF and preserve the table's look or show me how such a thing can be done?

Comment: This wouldn't exactly be generating a PDF directly, but you could use `window.print()` followed by Google Chrome's "Save as PDF" option

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to save HTML page as PDF using JavaScript or jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896592/is-it-possible-to-save-html-page-as-pdf-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: @ZacB It differs because the main aim of this post is to preserve the CSS styling of the table not just to export the page to PDF

Comment: Gotcha thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one, using @cloudformatter (see http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf)
Just took your input above and created this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zvx6eb7e/665/

Add the code for print, like this:

```
var click="return xepOnline.Formatter.Format('JSFiddle', 
{render:'download'})";
jQuery('#buttons').append('<button onclick="'+ click +'">PDF</button>');
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: it seems that as of today, your jsfiddle is not found anymore. Would you might want to update it? it is very helpful. thanks

Comment: @shifu Here is the offical usage document [css2pdf - Usage Instructions](http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.APIDoc.Usage)