# Convert a HTML file into PDF in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I need to download a HTML file in PDF format. I tried some plugins but that doesn't work. I need help.

```
import React from 'react';
class App extends React.Component {
    htmlToPdf()
    {
       //code need to be written
    }
    render() {

        return (
             <div>
              <button onClick={this.htmlToPdf}>download</button>
             </div>
           );

        }
     }


export default App;
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: tried html-pdf plugin

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896592/is-it-possible-to-save-html-page-as-pdf-using-javascript-or-jquery or use `window.print()`

Comment: Use chrome capabilities to save file as PDF.