# how to download a blade page in PDF format on click a button using java script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, laravel

*i tried this but did not got the output*

```
function downloadInnerHtml(filename, elId) {

    var elHtml = $(elId).pdf();
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    var mimeType = mimeType/'pdf';
    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    link.setAttribute('href','data:' + mimeType + ';charset=utf-8,' +    encodeURIComponent(elHtml));
    link.click();
}

 $(document).ready(function () {

 $('#download').click(function () {

                downloadInnerHtml(fileName, 'table4');
            });
 });
```

Comment: What is `$(elId).pdf();`

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896592/is-it-possible-to-save-html-page-as-pdf-using-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: e1Id is the name of div need to be download

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick='printDiv();'>Download Resume</a>

<div class="section-body" id="DivIdToPrint">
      ....
      ....
</div>

<script>
   function printDiv() 
   {
       var divToPrint=document.getElementById('DivIdToPrint');
       var newWin=window.open('','Print-Window');
       newWin.document.open();
       newWin.document.write('<html><head> 'link your used css'</head><body onload="window.print()">'+divToPrint.innerHTML+'</body></html>');
       newWin.document.close();
       setTimeout(function(){ newWin.close(); }, 10);
   }
</script>
```