# Content comes from the backend in xml format. How can I download it as pdf after the response returns

Tags: javascript

Content comes from the backend in xml format. This content needs to be downloaded as pdf. How can I download it as pdf after the response returns.

action function
Thats vue.js project and using axios.

```
store.dispatch(`${APP_STORE_MODULE_NAME}/${point}`, { id })
                    .then((response) => {
                        console.log(response)
                    }).catch((err) => {
                        console.log(error)
                    })
```

how look like response ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
...
...
</body>
</html>
```

I tried those but its not dowloading as pdf.

```
window.open('data:Application/octet-stream,' + encodeURIComponent(response.data));
window.open(response.data, "Test", "width=300,height=300,scrollbars=1,resizable=1");
window.open(URL.createObjectURL(response.data));
```

I want a see download as a blabla.pdf file.

if the response is like that

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

pdf must be like that

Hello World

Comment: The response seems to be an HTML file. Is there a PDF file linked somewhere there that you want, or do you want a PDF file with the HTML source code as text?

Comment: I don't want download HTML sources code as text. I edit my question.

Comment: Do the answers here help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896592/is-it-possible-to-save-html-page-as-pdf-using-javascript-or-jquery