# What is the easiest way to create complex PDF in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode4, uiwebview, quartz-2d

I am trying to generate some complex invoice data in PDF format. I know two Technique:-

1. By converting Data into HTML data via UIWebView and generate its PDF accordingly. But it is having issue of showing data Blur or unreadable if Zoom, when data is long in size. Cause it actually first create Image from HTML data and generate pdf.
2. Using QuartzCore technique mentioned in Ray-Wenderlich tutorial:-
   http://www.raywenderlich.com/6818/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2

Is there any way other then these above two? Also is it possible in the First technique to get data in UIWebView as vector based so that when it zoom it will not blur the data?

Thanks in Advance,
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

Use the Quartz 2D framework as described in the tutorial. You don't want to create a pixel image from the html because it does not scale and can get large.

Comment: Thanks phix, but the thing is my PDF is a bit complex, so the working Quartz become very complicated.

Comment: maybe you can use a web service to generate the PDF http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344176/is-there-a-web-service-for-converting-html-to-pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tableview with multi sections to create your invoice and convert it to an image(uiview----> image) and After that print that image to pdf (image--->pdf).