# Best way to convert selected area of Web page to PDF on server (server-based solution)

Tags: php, html, pdf, converters

I am trying to create a website where you can create some forms for your customers irl. I am trying to fit in function that allows you download the final version of your form (in PDf format).

I am looking for solution:

1. Some sort of plugin or way how you can add into PHP website function that allows you select area of website (obviously I want to convert only the form, not NAV nor footer of site, so the selected area will be everytime the same) to PDF.
2. Some other way that allows the user download his form as a picture.

But I need something that I can include into PHP based website, not C#.

Thank you for any solutions / advices!

Comment: This is difficult. Forms are difficult. Do you want the form to work in PDF? I think you do. This is impossible. Landing on the moon is easier. For making a picture there is the service: https://grabz.it/html-to-pdf-image-api.aspx

Comment: No, everything you will write / set in web page app (html / php) and then you just download final version (non-editable) pdf. Just for sending by mail, or printing. That forms will be like... Registration form or some kind of "Annoucement" like.

Comment: You can use the grabz service, I suggested, but only if you give it the form with entries from the user. I tested it, and it seems to work, so I have to take back that it is very difficult, it is doable. Don't forget about the privacy of your users though! There are probably alternative services that do a similar thing. Doing it all on your own server will still be quite difficult.

Comment: Don't you know, is there any free alternative API plugin like this? Something you can recommend.

Comment: I don't think anybody can afford, or wants, to provide this unlimited for free. So, no. However, https://pdflayer.com seems good. You get 100 free conversions per month, after that it is a subscription. With https://www.convertapi.com/web-pdf-api you can buy credits, so if your volume is low or variable, that would be a good option. I like a credit system, which is much more cost effective than a subscription. Basically, you can Google this, it's not difficult. You can even find an answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344176/is-there-a-web-service-for-converting-html-to-pdf

Comment: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-convert-html-div-to-pdf-format-in-jquery