# Somehow send command line commands on windows externally and get back the response

Tags: pdf, command, aix, universe, u2

Problem: Need to convert local html (with local images etc) to pdf from an AIX box running Universe 11.2.5 with System Builder

Current solution: FTP over html file to a Windows server which converts in batches and sends the e-mail to the destination

Proposed Solution: Do everything on the AIX box, from converting html to pdf and sending the e-mail.

Current problem: Unable to find a way to convert local html to PDF on the AIX box. I have been trying many different ways from trying to install Python3, but to no avail.

Comment: What you are asking is possible with UniVerse BASIC.  The Basic Extensions manual has information on sockets, as well as the more general UniVerse Basic commands manual.  There is even information on base64 encoding.  Please see https://docs.rocketsoftware.com/nxt/gateway.dll?f=templates$fn=default.htm

Comment: @Mike Hi mike, are you saying its possible to do with sockets then?

Comment: I think you might need to refine your requirements a bit to get more specific help. Neither getting html from within UniVerse nor creating a PDF in aix is exceptionally difficult, but I am not even sure which system UniVerse is running on here.

Comment: @VanAmburg Hi, i have redone the specifications, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only really difficult part of the process is getting the HTML to render into a format will properly display your html into pages that are suitable for printing. There is a fair amount of magic that goes on between HTTP:GET and clicking print on a browser window that needs to be accounted for.

I was trying accomplish something similar many moons ago on AIX but kind of ran into a skill level/time wall because I was going to have essentially create a headless browser to render the html. It looks like there are now some utilities that you might be able to leverage. I found this recent updated article on Super User that actually got me somewhat excited, especially since I don't use AIX anymore so precompiled binaries and well understood and easily attainable dependencies are something I can actually have in my life.

https://superuser.com/questions/280552/how-can-i-render-a-website-as-an-image-from-the-shell

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be several questions rolled into this one item.

Converting HTML to PDF, while that is just a data manipulation that you could do in basic, writing such code would be a large task.  The option you use sending it to another system is valid, but put more points of failure into the system.  I would think you could find code to do it on the AIX box.

Rocket plans on getting the MV Python to work on AIX, this will make the converting of html to PDF much easier since there are a lot of open source modules.

As for my suggestion of using sockets, that would be if you intend to send it to a service that will take the htms, and return the pdf document.

i.e. [Is there a web service for converting HTML to PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344176/is-there-a-web-service-for-converting-html-to-pdf)

Once you have the pdf document, you can either store it in a UniVerse type-19 file, or do the base64 encoding and store it in UniVerse hash file.

Hope this helps,
Mike