# Server timed out for a heavy mpdf transaction in Codeigniter Application

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, mpdf

I have a code that needs to process heavy dataset and print its pdf using mpdf library. Server terminates the process after few seconds due to which transaction never completes. If I fetch 120 records and generate the pdf, things go fine. But for a heavy dataset I get 504 server time out error. I have tried the following tweaks in my php code, but those didnot work:

```
ini_set("pcre.backtrack_limit", "10000000");
ini_set("max_allowed_packet ", "1024M");
ini_set("max_execution_time ", "1800");
ini_set('max_input_time','0');
```

In `.htaccess` too, I have tried the following:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_value post_max_size 200M
   php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
   php_value memory_limit 300M
   php_value max_execution_time 259200
   php_value max_input_time 259200
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1200
</IfModule>
```

but no wonders.

Answer (score 0):

Shared hostings will often not allow you to change PHP settings. Or the settings can be changed in the administration interface of the hosting, not in the .htaccess file or in the code.

But, generally, it is not a good idea to generate large PDFs during a HTTP request.

If available, use a cron job or a job queue.

For fastest results, generate multiple smaller PDFs and concatenate them with an external program such as GhostScript.

Alternatively, you can try to use a web service, if any supports all your needs. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5344424/819007